# Shell is there a way to use pipes to name a variable?

Tags: shell

Let's say I have a text file that has three lines. Its called a

```
1
2
3
```

Is there a way to make this possible:

```
$ x='cat a | head -1'
```

Comment: Do you really want to *name* the variable 1, or do you want to *assign the value* 1 to a variable named `x`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is using a shell loop to process text considered bad practice?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice)

Comment: You *can* do it, but the answer to "*should* you do this?" is a definite "no."  However, look into **command substitution**, which is what you're looking for.  (And it's a useful tool that has its place...this just isn't it.)

Comment: Very few questions are legitimately duplicates of that one, and this isn't one of them.

Comment: This question has nothing to do with shell looops.  It is just "how do I do [command substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_substitution)?".   Answer is `x=$(cat a | head -1)` or, since the `cat` is unnecessary, `x=$(head -1 a)`

Answer (score 2):

What you're trying to do is called [command substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_substitution), which puts the output of a command onto the command-line of another.  e.g. to provide arguments for the other command, or to assign the output to a variable.

You almost had the right syntax.  You need to use `$()` around your command.  e.g.

`x=$(cat a | head -1)` or, since the cat is unnecessary, `x=$(head -1 a)`

backticks (`) can also be used but are considered obsolete, as they have a number of problems (including inability to nest them, and difficulty in distinguishing them from single-quotes).